# Urql - What does a second element in query do?

Tags: javascript, typescript, urql

I have defined my query as so:

```
import * as Urql from 'urql';

export function useIsFollowingQuery(options: Omit<Urql.UseQueryArgs<IsFollowingQueryVariables>, 'query'>) {
  return Urql.useQuery<IsFollowingQuery>({ query: IsFollowingDocument, ...options });
};
```

When I am using it in a component:

```
const [
        { fetching: IsFollowingFetching, data: IsFollowingData },
        func,
] = useIsFollowingQuery()
```

I can get this `func` element.

When I call it: `func()`, nothing seem to happen.

I am using them in a component like this:

```
const TestComponent = () => {
  const [
          { fetching: IsFollowingFetching, data: IsFollowingData },
          func,
  ] = useIsFollowingQuery()

  return (
    <>
      {!IsFollowingFetching ? (
        <div className="btn-container">
          {IsFollowingData.isFollowing === 0 ? (
            <button> Follow </button>
          ) : (
            <button> Unfollow </button>
          )}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};
```

My question is what is this `func` element, and what it is doing.

Comment: How are you using the fetching and data variables inside the Component?

Comment: I mean the destructured { fetching and data } properties that are returned from the useIsFollowingQuery() call

Comment: Are you using these variables anywhere in the code? Can you share some more of the Component code?

Comment: Also, I would suggest that you destructure the 'error' variable returned from the useQuery to check whether there's an error happening during the request.

Comment: You can check the Networks Tab too, to see whether the XHR request actually takes place and whether it succeeds or not.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis editted my answer

Comment: You should consult the documentation in order to understand the purpose and role of the 'func': https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/api/urql/

Comment: My guess is that there's something wrong going with the request, that's why you also need to destructure a third 'error' variable from the useQuery and check it.

Comment: Check their example, where they are testing whether the error variable is truthy: https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/basics/react-preact/#run-a-first-query

Comment: If you find a solution on this one, please don't forget to share it as an answer.